# Thin blank line in Chrome when superimposing PNG's but not in Safari on Mac

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, safari, png

I have two layers of png's at the exact same position in a web page, the top one being transparent. Everything looks good in Photoshop before export. Everything is great in Safari (Mac and Ipad), but i have a weird white line in Chrome (and a lighter one in Firefox).

Chrome
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/nh8kf811h6b6v7a/2014-04-16%20at%2012.12.png

Safari
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/7iu3c0yh4rwa0yt/2014-04-16%20at%2012.16.png

```
<div id="layers">

  <img id="band_img" src="https://lxproject.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/band/img/643/Diana1_Rg_bottom_band.png" uid="upper_main_band">
  <img id="cut_img" src="https://lxproject.s3.amazonaws.com/uploads/cut/img/228/Diana1_Rg_bottom.png" uid="upper_main_cut">    

</div>
```

and css :

```
  <style>
  #layers {
    overfow:hidden;
    height: 500px;
    background: #FFF;
    position: relative;
  }
  #layers img {
    position:absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
  }
  </style>
```

Fiddle :http://jsfiddle.net/yVu3v/

Thank you in advance

Comment: Could you reproduce this in a jsfiddle?

Comment: I can't see the "weird white line" in the screenshots

Comment: Here is the image with an arrow : https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/1qj71us90r1qpkn/2014-04-17%20at%2014.42.png

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yVu3v/

Comment: Does this need to change size? The white line is being created when the image is being scaled down. If you recreate the images at the size you want them to be it should go away. If you allow the images to be at their natural size, the line also disappears: http://jsfiddle.net/yVu3v/1/